# Library for universal XML parser app

Tags: xml, html, parsing, universal-code

I have developed a simple HTML 5 app that parses a list of products in XML form and displays the data.

I would like to extend the app to work with any valid XML input and create a web based UI to allow the user to view the XML structure and label is according to it's application.

In other words, instead of defining node names like "product" and "price", names of all elements are pulled from the XML, then the user defines what they do and where they go.

My question: is there a library or method which exists that is capable of outputting XML structures dynamically?